# Using tr as label-input wrapper in simple-form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I may be old school,and I've been through many div/span attempts and swore off tables at one time, but there are just some good uses for tables, one of them, imho, is a form. I prefer to shade my label fields with a different background color. I've tried may ways, but if the input (actually either) side overflows the width, it will mess up the label background. I'd look at another attempt, but I really prefer a table approach.

In 2.x I set my configuration to:

```
config.wrappers :tag => :tr, :class => :input,
  :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|

  b.use :label, :wrap_with => {:tag => :td, :class => :label}
  b.use :input, :wrap_with => {:tag => :td, :class => :input}
  b.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :hint }
  b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :caption, :class => :error }
```

Works great!, except for errors. I first had it as a span and it went to the top of the table. I then set it to caption and, at least in Safari, it ends tbody and puts in the caption and starts another tbody - but it screws up the table flow.

Is there a way I can force the error to be in the input wrapper? Or any other approach? I'd even accept (and maybe this is what I should do) putting the error in the main message like the scaffold approach. Didn't think about that until I started to write this, but I guess I could not use simple forms error stuff and go back to the scaffold approach.

At least I think you can do that. For instance, I didn't know (and could not find in documentation - but I didn't look real hard!) that you could use regular form_for input (e.g., f.text_field) mixed with f.input. Great for things like putting City, St, Zip on one row.

Comment: If you have want to put city state zip in one row perhaps u should over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071685/ruby-on-rails-simple-form-add-image-next-to-each-input-field/14338077#14338077)

Comment: Check the answer mention over [here][1]

Hope this help

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071685/ruby-on-rails-simple-form-add-image-next-to-each-input-field/14338077#14338077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should answer my own question. I ended up not using Simple Forms error notification and went back to the scaffold method.

I configured my wrappers as follows:

```
config.wrappers :tag => :tr, :class => :input,
  :hint_class => :field_with_hint, :error_class => :field_with_errors do |b|
    b.use :label, :wrap_with => {:tag => :td, :class => :label}
    b.use :input, :wrap_with => {:tag => :td, :class => :input}
```

Wrote a helper method for errors:

```
def show_form_errors(instance)
  if instance.errors.any?
    errors = content_tag(:h2, pluralize(instance.errors.count, "error") +"prohibited this project from being saved:")
    list = content_tag :ul do
      e = ""
      instance.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        e <<"<li>#{msg}</li>"
      end
      e.html_safe
    end
    return content_tag(:div, (errors + list),:id => "error_explanation").html_safe
  end
end

# instead of
  # = f.error_notification
# I used
  # = show_form_errors(@event)
```

Had to tweak the CSS for error_explanation because of how I had borders defined on my table rows (just border-bottom) and add !important to wrap the tr with a red border:

```
.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  border:solid 3px red!important;
  background-color:pink;
}
```

Works fine and I am content with this method.